# I'm trying to display shapes using canvas and they aren't showing up

Tags: javascript, canvas, shapes

I am working on a simple game (following a tutorial on Zenva Academy) and, although I've followed the instructions to a T, I can't seem to get my canvas shapes to show up in the browser. Here is the code I have so far:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementByID('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let screenWidth = 1000;
let screenHeight = 500;

class GameCharacter {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
  }
}

var blueSquare = new GameCharacter(
  50, 50, 50, 50, "rgb(0, 0, 255)"
);
var rectangle = new GameCharacter(
  75, 75, 100, 50, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"
);
var redSquare = new GameCharacter(
  100, 50, 50, 50, "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
);

var draw = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
  ctx.fillRect(blueSquare.x, blueSquare.y, blueSquare.width, blueSquare.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = rectangle.color;
  ctx.fillRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = redSquare.color;
  ctx.fillRect(redSquare.x, redSquare.y, redSquare.width, redSquare.height);

}

var step = function() {
  draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 4px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='1000' height='500'></canvas>
```

I am still fairly new to this and this is the first question I've ever asked on a forum. Let me know if I'm doing something wrong. LOL!

***I am using:***

**OS:** Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

**Browser:** Tried both Chrome and Microsoft Edge

**Code Editor:** Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple typo - you have written `getElementByID`, while you should have `getElementById`. (This shows up immediately in your browser's developer tools' console.)

Then, you'll need to call `step()` once to kick things off.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let screenWidth = 1000;
let screenHeight = 500;

class GameCharacter {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
  }
}

var blueSquare = new GameCharacter(
  50, 50, 50, 50, "rgb(0, 0, 255)"
);
var rectangle = new GameCharacter(
  75, 75, 100, 50, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"
);
var redSquare = new GameCharacter(
  100, 50, 50, 50, "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
);

var draw = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
  ctx.fillRect(blueSquare.x, blueSquare.y, blueSquare.width, blueSquare.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = rectangle.color;
  ctx.fillRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = redSquare.color;
  ctx.fillRect(redSquare.x, redSquare.y, redSquare.width, redSquare.height);

}

var step = function() {
  draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

step();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 4px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='1000' height='500'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I hate when it's something as simple as a typo, but then also glad it's something so easy to fix. I appreciate you finding that for me, I just couldn't see it and I've been staring at it for at least 30 minutes trying to figure it out.

Comment: You should keep your browser's developer tools (console) open to catch those silly mistakes and maybe switch to a smarter editor, such as Visual Studio Code, to help you catch them earlier. :) Glad I could help!